# JBACI java compile error

Tags: java, compiler-errors, ioexception

im trying to do my sempahore homework with JBACI, but i cant use it (after long steps to make it run, im sure i did them right) because terminal shows me an IO error. im trying to sample the following code:

```
// Demonstate jBACI graphics; without barrier program.
#include "gdefs.cm"
const
int SQUARE1 = 1;    int SQUARE2 = 2;       
int BARRER = 3;     int DELTA = 11;    int Xfinal = 600;

void MoveS1() {
    int i=0,r;
    while (i <= Xfinal) {
        r = random(DELTA);
        i = i + r;
        moveby(SQUARE1, r, 0);
    }
}

void MoveS2() {
    int i=0,r;
    while (i <= Xfinal) {
        r = random(DELTA);
        i = i + r;
        moveby(SQUARE2, r, 0);           
    }
}

void main() {
    create(SQUARE1, RECTANGLE, RED,   30, 50,  30, 30);
    create(SQUARE2, RECTANGLE, BLUE,  30, 100, 30, 30);
    create(BARRER, LINE, BLACK, 350,10,350,400);
    cobegin {
        MoveS2();MoveS1();
    }
}
```

and i get the following in terminal:

```
root@pochi-ThinkPad-T61:/home/pochi/ProgramasJBACI# java -jar jbaci.jar
I/O error from: /usr/bin/bapas alien.pm  java.io.IOException: Cannot run program          
"/usr/bin/bapas" (in directory "/home/pochi/ProgramasJBACI/examples"): 
java.io.IOException:     error=2, No such file or directory
```

btw im compiling with JBACI

tnx for help

this isnt homework I need to know why i cant compile right... did i set a path wrong??
also i followed this instructions: in spanish....
http://inform.pucp.edu.pe/~inf232/Semestre-2007-2/Laboratorio-4/index.htm

Comment: "im trying to do my sempahore homework" ... "this isnt homework I need to know why i cant compile right" ??

Comment: with the same configuration Windows users have been able to compile, I only have ubuntu and haven't been able to make it compile. I need it to compile first, then I can begin my HW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what JBACI is, but that looks to me like when you run the jar, it's trying to kick off another process to start `/usr/bin/bapas`, and the error indicates that file doesn't exist. You'll need to install whatever that is before your java command will work.

Comment: in the part where it says: Cannot run program "usr/bin/bapas" should that be a program or a path?